Repeatability of Measurement Statistic
I have a dataset of measurement at time 1 and measurement at time 2 grouped by their location. My advisor asked me to get R^2 of the data, but I am unsure of whether this is the best method to report the error. For the R^2 equation I am also curious if it matters what I put as the average value subtracted in the numerator. Does it make a difference if I use measurement 1's average vs. measurement 2's? Curious if R^2 is the right way to go.
If R^2 isn't, would RMSE be the way to do it? I did RMSE but we normalized the data so the units are in standard deviations. The RMSE came out to ~1 standard deviation but we don't know if its good as its measuring a unique kind of data so there is nothing to go off of. Curious if there was a way to standardize RMSE to state whether the measurement device was repeatable.

Data don't have $R^2$ values, but least squares regression models do.  Please tell us what your model is.  Your description is so vague that it's difficult to determine what you might have in mind.

I have two sets of measurements using the same device at the same location. I want to see if the device I’m using is repeatable (it’s a geophysical method so there are sources of error associated with nearby electromagnetic sources). Would an R^2 between the measurements be an appropriate way to determine its repeatability if the graph is (M1i, M2i) where M1i is measurement at location i for the first measurement and M2i is the measurement at location i for the second measurement. I can easily get the RMSE but I don’t know how to interpret this to say whether it’s repeatable or not.

Wouldn't "repeatability" assess the discrepancies between that graph and the line of equality?  There are many methods to do that.  The standard deviation of the differences would be one way.  It's related to $R^2$ but it is expressed in the same units as the measurements and not confounded by the amount of variation among the measurements themselves.  But there are many other solution, depending on how you intend to use or interpret this discrepancy.

Please add new info as an edit to the post, nt oly as a comment. Comments on this site are ephemeral and often seen only by a few
